# What is the meaning of this question about matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Consider the matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 \\ -7 & 1 \\ 2 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 6 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\ -1 & 2 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$AB=\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 6 & 6 & 0 \\ -43 & -5 & -26 & -35 \\ 3 &20 & 26 &10  \end{bmatrix}$$

Is $AB$ correct?

-Express each column of the matrix $AB$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. 
-Express each row of the matrix $AB$ or linear combination of the rows of $B$.

Any help will be appreciated or any documentation in relation with the exercice.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the question? It's not clear to what matrix that refers and also the grammar seems off.

Comment: @cdwe I updated with the full question.

Comment: It might be clearer if the questions were "Express each column(row) of the matrix $AB$ as a linear combination ..."

Comment: @Henry  This is the question of my Algebra teacher.. maybe is not well formed.

Comment: Have you calculated $AB$?

Comment: @Henry Yes but I'm not sure if it's okay.

Comment: For example $[3\,\,20\,\,26\,\,10]=2[6\,\,1\,\,4\,\,5]+9[-1\,\,2\,\,2\,\,0]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your product is correct.

Let $a_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\-7\\2\end{bmatrix}$ and $a_2=\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\9\end{bmatrix}$ be the two columns of $A$ and $b_1=\begin{bmatrix}6&1&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ and $b_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&2&0\end{bmatrix}$ be the two rows of $B$.

You can write $AB$ as follows:

$$\text{col}_1(AB)=(6)a_1+(-1)a_2$$
$$\text{col}_2(AB)=(1)a_1+(2)a_2$$
$$\text{col}_3(AB)=(4)a_1+(2)a_2$$
$$\text{col}_4(AB)=(5)a_1+(0)a_2$$

Or:

$$\text{row}_1(AB)=(0)b_1+(3)b_2$$
$$\text{row}_2(AB)=(-7)b_1+(1)b_2$$
$$\text{row}_3(AB)=(2)b_1+(9)b_2$$

Comment: Thank you!  this is the answer to both ?

Comment: Yes @devtreat in the first one the columns of $AB$ are written in terms of columns of $A$ and the second one rows of $AB$ in terms of rows of $B$.